# Is sending multiple files in one HTTP request good?

Tags: http, multipartform-data

I am developing a Web API that analyze images.
There is a need that user have to send the API, 10 images. 
I am using multipart/form-data as request enc-type

I know i can send all 10 images in one request but I thought, then there will be a probability of data lose. 
So should I consider sending 10 images in 10 separate requests?
Is there any other way that I have missed.

Comment: I would consider things like request length as well; can your system even handle 10 potentially large images in one request? I would go for individual images and above all, make the processing asynchronous. It really depends on what the customer wants.

Comment: Yes I can. They are not very big files. What i fear is about a data lost.
And thank you for your advice. I will try asynchronous way.